# plugins for cakephp view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am very new to cakephp and I see a folder plugin in my application

when I go to the site I see the address as

mysite.com/user/mergerdata

mergerdata is a plugin

When I click on add I see this

mysite.com/account/mergerdata/add

so when I go to app/plugins/mergerdata/controllers/merger_controller

I dont see an add action, But I do see the user_add action there

Am I looking at the wrong place. Where is User comning from. Where is Add coming from ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"user" is a prefix, similar to an admin prefix. You can read more about it on http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing

Basically, this feature allows you to have different methods for different levels of users, and the prefix ("user") is added to the front of the method name ("add").